# How to screenshot BIOS

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, bios

I need to make screenshot of BIOS Award 1984-2009 F8 setup for my Project without using devices like camera. Is there any way to do it? I tried some emulators, but they won't work.

Comment: Which emulators did you try and how did they not work? Have you gone through the list of the results when Googling `How to screenshot BIOS` and verified that there is nothing of service? Have you checked out the corresponding [Superuser.com question?](http://superuser.com/questions/290432/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-the-pc-before-it-boots-up)

Comment: Ditto.  What emulators have you tried and why did they not work?  Also, do you have a system that can run all these versions [by inserting the ROM]?  If you have a real system, you may be able to connect the VGA port to something [other than a monitor] that can capture the output.  And, why not camera [carefully aligned, this is just about as good]?  Can you hack the BIOS itself?

Comment: I don't have any device that can record vga screen. I tested a lot of emulators, unfortunately I can't remember their names. Also i have tried every key combination. This BIOS does not have a feature for creating screenshots. I have never worked with emulators before, so I could make some mistakes. Is there any guide on how to do this?

Comment: I'd just use my phone to snap a quick screen shot. Not perfect, but usable.

Comment: The link Pekka provided is very informative.  A VGA video frame grabber is about $300. But, you can get a VGA card that also has S-video output.  With an S-video video grabber (connects to other host via USB) you can capture whatever [price of USB grabber ~$25].  Or, run the BIOS under a VM like vmware or xen.  But, seriously, an emulator such as QEMU should also do the job. You can't remember what emulators you tried? I'd start again, but this time, take detailed notes. If all of the above is too much work, use a camera as the chances for a "print screen" key in the BIOS is nearly zero.

Comment: How about a [remote KVM](http://www.amazon.com/1PORT-PS2-Remote-KVM-Spider/dp/B000OH7QNI/ref=pd_sim_147_3?ie=UTF8&dpID=41H%2BIRwRqgL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=1NX9Q7K34CZBR4HT5P7J)?

Answer (score 0):

In some UEFI putting an USB key and pressing F12 works. Hope it helps one person at least.